# Movie player Totem shuts down without any error message

Tags: 10.04, video-player

I'm using **Ubuntu 10.04** and have an issue with **Movie Player Totem**. Recently I got a great movie. For those who know *"Wall Street" 1987*. So I was watching it and for no reason totem shut himself down.

Did any of you have such issue?
Is there any solution for that?

---

**UPD:**

When I execute totem from command line as root it gives me such message:

```
(totem:2986): Totem-WARNING **: Failed to create dbus proxy for org.gnome.SettingsDaemon: Could not get owner of name 'org.gnome.SettingsDaemon': no such name
```

But will I start it as root or just as user doesn't matter it shuts down without any error message in terminal.

Comment: Try executing Totem Player from the command line. Open the terminal then type `totem`. It'll launch and messages will be piped to the command prompt. Try watching your movie again and when it closes without an error - edit your question and include it's output. That should help drill down a cause.

Answer (score 2):

As mentioned in this group post ( http://groups.google.com/group/linux.gentoo.user/browse_thread/thread/74fe3091604481c9)

this error happens when you use a different window manager than gnome.

But according to this post this error should not cause totem to crash.

Try using `vlc` or `mplayer`. Maybe your movie file is corrupted

Comment: Done. I read myself, that VLC player is great. Especially for watching 720p movies on not so strong hardware. But it would be nice to have a clear view on what's wrong with totem. Why does it behave like that.

Comment: Some video files (malformed .mkv files are usually the culprit) do not like being played under totem.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe Your movie file is somehow corrupted and maybe some programs (vlc, mplayer) have better error toleration than totem. Just speculating about that.

Comment: are you asking me? :) How should I know, that? :D If I knew, I wouldn't probably ask this question at all. :)

Answer (score 0):

Try to delete totem config file / folder in your home directory ($HOME/.config/totem).

If it still not working, try to delete gstreamer configuration directory ($HOME/.gstreamer-0.10)

Don't worry, that configuration will be created again when you run totem or gstreamer based applications.

Comment: Do I need to deletem both those files or I can just move them elsewhere?

Comment: just delete ,it's fine.